# How to simulate hung task in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I just changed following configurations in /etc/sysctl.conf :

```
# Reboot 5 seconds after panic
kernel.panic = 5

# Panic if a hung task was found
kernel.hung_task_panic = 1

# Setup timeout for hung task to 300 seconds
kernel.hung_task_timeout_secs = 300
```

I want to test if `kernel.hung_task_panic = 1` and `kernel.hung_task_timeout_sec = 300` are working. How do I simulate the hung task in linux to test the two configurations. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 Server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can freeze a filesystem and then trigger a write, like this:

```
# fsfreeze --freeze /path/to/mountpoint
# echo crap > /path/to/mountpoint/file
```

since you intend to trigger a crash, I strongly suggest you dd a few MB file to a tmpfs mountpoint, losetup (get /dev/loop0 or so), mkfs and finally mount that.

Comment: I am using zfs filesystem and when I try to freeze any mountpoint I get the error:`fsfreeze: /opt/storage: freeze failed: Operation not supported`

Comment: zfs not supporting freezing is kind of expected - you can just snapshot, which removes the need to have freezing. don't simulate using zfs but e.g. ext4 or xfs.

Comment: I tried with ext4 filesystem and it worked like a charm. Thanks ! :)